# Necesito verificar cuando alguien se loguee en Windows incorrectamente y realizar una acción

Tags: c#, windows

Hola estoy programando en **C#** y tengo un servicio que se inicia con **Windows** y necesito saber cómo realizar una acción al detectart cuando un usario se loguea incorrectamente al iniciar sesión en Windows

Comment: Creo que la unica forma sería activando el log de eventos de Login,aunque nunca lo he hecho asi que no puedo ayudarte mas. Echa un vistazo [aqui](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd941635(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar lo eventos de la clase

[SystemEvents Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx)

para detectar cuando se autentica en windows, aunque no veo que haya especificamente un evento de login incorrecto

---

Sino podrias evaluar utilizar los eventos de `WMI` por medio de `Win32_LogonSession` y

[ManagementEventWatcher Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

como se plantea aqui

[Get notified from logon and logoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282231/get-notified-from-logon-and-logoff)

```
private readonly static WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), "TargetInstance ISA \"Win32_LogonSession\"");


ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(HandleEvent);
watcher.Start();
```

asignando el handler que se dispara cuando se produce un evento de wmi

```
private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject f = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];

     //resto codigo
}
```